# How could I avoid the duplicated else branches?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to refactor this method in a more Kotlin way and remove the many if else with repeated code. I can't seem to find a working way.

```
fun update(type: Update) {
    if (model.list.isNotEmpty()) {
      fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList? = this.firstOrNull { userList -> userList.listType == listType }

      val userList = type.list.filter(getTabSelectedListType())

      if (userList != null) {
        val listToShow = userList.toShoppingWrapper(model.cart)

        adapterShopping.update(listToShow, type.updateCurrentList)
        if (listToShow.isNotEmpty()) with(binding) {
          recyclerView.visible()
          emptyLayoutMyProducts.emptyView.gone()
          emptyLayoutFavorites.emptyView.gone()
          emptyLayoutLists.emptyView.gone()
        } else when (binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)?.tag) {
            PRODUCTS -> showMyProductsEmptyLayout()
            FAVORITES -> showFavoritesEmptyLayout()
        }
      } else when (binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)?.tag) {
        PRODUCTS -> showMyProductsEmptyLayout()
        FAVORITES -> showFavoritesEmptyLayout()
      }
    } else when (binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)?.tag) {
      PRODUCTS -> showMyProductsEmptyLayout()
      FAVORITES -> showFavoritesEmptyLayout()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just put all the `else` code inside one as they are same and always getting executed

Comment: they are the same, but not always executed. If I just leave the one outside, if then userList is null, it never goes to the else branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nullability to do your sequence of successful actions. A null or empty value at the end goes to the same else branch.

```
fun update(type: Update) {
    fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList? = this.firstOrNull { userList -> userList.listType == listType }

    val userList = if (model.list.isEmpty()) null else type.list.filter(getTabSelectedListType())
    val listToShow = userList?.toShoppingWrapper(model.cart)?.also {
        adapterShopping.update(it, type.updateCurrentList)
    }
    if (!listToShow.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        with(binding) {
          recyclerView.visible()
          emptyLayoutMyProducts.emptyView.gone()
          emptyLayoutFavorites.emptyView.gone()
          emptyLayoutLists.emptyView.gone()
        }
    } else when (binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)?.tag) {
        PRODUCTS -> showMyProductsEmptyLayout()
        FAVORITES -> showFavoritesEmptyLayout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
    var userList = null
    var listToShow = emptyList<Specify type here>()
    if (model.list.isNotEmpty()) {
        fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList? = this.firstOrNull { userList -> userList.listType == listType }

        userList = type.list.filter(getTabSelectedListType())

        if (userList != null) {
             listToShow = userList.toShoppingWrapper(model.cart)

            adapterShopping.update(listToShow, type.updateCurrentList)
            if (listToShow.isNotEmpty()) with(binding) {
                recyclerView.visible()
                emptyLayoutMyProducts.emptyView.gone()
                emptyLayoutFavorites.emptyView.gone()
                emptyLayoutLists.emptyView.gone()
            } 
        } 
    } 
    if(model.list.isEmpty()||userList == null ||listToShow==null|| listToShow.isEmpty() ){
        when (binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)?.tag) {
            PRODUCTS -> showMyProductsEmptyLayout()
            FAVORITES -> showFavoritesEmptyLayout()
        }
    }
```